# Run program after wpf windows form appears

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello i have problem with wpf (c#) project. this is my source

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

i want to run my program

```
MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

after windows form appears ... but in this code when i start the program, just first show Test in message box and after that windows form appears ! what should i do to first windows form appears and after that a message box open to show the (Test)? i am using visual studio 2015 (WPF) project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your code in the `Window_Load` event:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

**EDIT:** To work with longer operations like (*used a function with more than 10 function inside* as you wanted) you could use [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        //Longer Process (//set the operation in another thread so that the UI thread is kept responding)
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {                    
            //use the Dispatcher to "return" to the UI thread
            //To change the UI elements like label you should put them here like : label1.Text = ""; 
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that's worked but is there other way? i can't Understand this action ! (this code)! !

Comment: @MyJustWorking...It just waiting for an event to occur. Each time you have a long process you can put it inside `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and while it's doing that long process your UI is still responsible.

Comment: there is other problem ... when my program start with this code, my mouse cursor turning and i cant use other windows form actions until process done ... is there any way to solve this too?

Comment: @To change the UI elements like label you should put them inside `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` like this: `//Longer Process
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {                    
            label1.Text = "";
        }`

Comment: Perhaps things were different with WPF 5 years ago, but this does not work today.  Loaded is still too early to guarantee that the main window is on-screen before the code executes.