# Changing Text On Button Click, Then Again After Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a program that corrects values in text files. In my xaml I have a textbox that is supposed to report the status/progress. "waiting"=before program starts, "processing"= program is processing files, "done"= files have been processed.

Here is my xaml code for the text field and the RUN button:

```
<TextBox x:Name="statusBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="130,332,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="waiting" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" >
<Button Content="Run" 
            Name="Run" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="562,27,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="53" 
            Click="Run_Click"
            RenderTransformOrigin="-0.305,0.487" Height="19">
        <Button.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup Name="btnOpen"/>
        </Button.BindingGroup>
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-0.848"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
```

Here is the problem I am having:

I have tried this many different ways. What I have below is the most recent attempt.

```
//In XAML, the status defaults to "waiting".
public class Operate
{
public void operations()
{
 statusBox.Text = "processing";
 ... Perform Text Operations
 status.Text = "finished";
}
}
```

When I run the program, I get see "waiting" in the status text box. However, when I click Run, the program begins but the text still says "waiting". Then, when the program has finished running, the text changes to "finished" without changing to "processing" in between.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have programmed many console applications, but am relatively new to wpf.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is just a typo but `statusBox.Text` and not `status.Text`. Anyway, if you remove everything and keep `statusBox.Text = "processing";` does it change?

Comment: To work with longer operations  you need to use `ThreadPool`. Here is an example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521365/run-program-after-wpf-windows-form-appears

Comment: There is really a hundred ways of going about this, but the best will be using ASYNC and Binding. Once you learn how to start binding in WPF/XAML it will go a long way.

Comment: What is the Operate class that you have? is it the code behind for XAML file or a view model?

Comment: Thanks to all. Yes this was a typo. I will look into ASYNC and Threadpool. Maybe they're the same thing, but I will find out. Thanks again to all!

Comment: What's wrong with setting the text of the statusbox.text = "waiting" as the first line of your Run_Click method and the last statement as statusbox.text = "finished"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start running, your UI won't be updated until it ends running the current thread. 
After completing the task, your status will be updated very fast from processing to finished, so you won't see the change. 
I recommend using a background worker to perform longer operations and still have the UI operational.

See this howto: [Use a background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look into using a `BackgroundWorker`. It appears the UI is being blocked while processing your requests.

[MSDN BackgroundWorker Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said the problem is that all your code is executing on the same thread. Your operations are running on the UI thread, which means it cannot respond to things like changes as you are trying to do.

The way around this is move your work onto a new thread.

(This assumes a newer version of the .NET framework that supports async/await syntax)

```
public class Operate
{
public async void operations()
{
 statusBox.Text = "processing";

 await Task.Run(()=>{
 //do work here
 });

 status.Text = "finished";
}
}
```

Keep in mind that since that Task.Run command executes on a different thread it cannot access the UI. If you need it to have some information from the UI, you can pass it in the Task.Run call like so:

```
await Task.Run(mydata=>{
 //do stuff, with mydata variable
});
```

If you need to return something to display on the UI then you can do this:

```
var myReturnValue = await Task.Run(mydata=>{
   //do work
   return myNewReturnData;
});

//can do something with your return data here.
```

If you need the ability for the user to click a different button to cancel the transaction look up the CancellationToken class.