# MediaElement hang UI thread while loading video

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement, doubleanimation

I have a WPF application  that run some animations (DoubleAnimation).

When I load a video using `MediaElement`, the animation freezes for some milliseconds. It looks terrible on the animation.

```
mElement = new MediaElement();
mElement.Source = new Uri(model.Filename);
mElement.Play();
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: To work with long operations or operations that cause the UI to be locked you need to use `ThreadPoo`. Example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521365/run-program-after-wpf-windows-form-appears

Comment: The problem is that "mElement.Source = ..." must be called on the UI thread. When moving to another thread it throws a "System.InvalidOperationException"