# Error when adding items to listbox on many threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, listbox

I have a WPF application and i want to add items to listbox on many threads.
When i do something like this

```
        listBox.Items.Clear();
        var lastgames = db.GameResults.OrderByDescending(c => c.DataGry).ToList();
        Parallel.ForEach(lastgames, game =>
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(game.score);
        });
```

It obviously throws and exception

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I've heard about background workers in WPF but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: To work with long operations or operations that cause the UI to be locked you need to use `ThreadPool` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521365/run-program-after-wpf-windows-form-appears

Comment: @S.Akbari ive used ur code and replaced parallel.foreach to normal foreach is it what i should do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since UI element can only be accessed from the thread on which they were originally created on, i.e. the UI thread, it makes no sense to use a `Parallel.ForEach` to add items to a ListBox.

You should use a simple foreach loop:

```
listBox.Items.Clear();
var lastgames = db.GameResults.OrderByDescending(c => c.DataGry).ToList();
foreach(var game in lastgames)
    listBox.Items.Add(game.score);
```

The other option would be add the items to a thread-safe collection and then set the ItemsSource property of the ListBox to this collection once it has been populated:

```
 object _lock = new _lock();
 List<int> scores = new List<int>();
 listBox.Items.Clear();
 var lastgames = db.GameResults.OrderByDescending(c => c.DataGry).ToList();
 Parallel.ForEach(lastgames, game =>
 {
     lock (_lock)
         scores.Add(game.score);
 });
 listBox.ItemsSource = scores;
```

This would be kind of pointless though since you still need to synchronize access to the collection in each iteration of the loop. So you better use a simple foreach loop and add all items on the same thread.

Comment: Blocking a collection is that what i was looking for. Thanks man for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use UI controls from other threads other than UI thread. you should use dispatcher instead.

For ex:

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.Background,
  new Action(() => {
      listBox.Items.Add(game.score);
 }));
```